# Symfony Command sending emails, missing absolute URLs in twig

Tags: php, symfony, docker, cron

There are a few questions covering this issue but none of them are solving my problem. This is a Symfony 2.8 application running in a PHP 7.1 docker container.

When the command is run as cron, the absolute URLs are using `localhost` in emails. I've tried both suggestions in the [documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/request_context.html) - configuring on the command itself and globally in parameters.

Everything works until the command is run by cron - even if I run the same manually. For example, running the following on the host into the container correctly generates the absolute URLs:

```
docker-compose exec --user www-data application sh -c "cd /var/www/html && /usr/local/bin/php app/console my:command -e=stage"
```

But my cron is reverting to localhost:

```
1-59/3 * * * * www-data cd /var/www/html && /usr/local/bin/php app/console my:command -e=stage
```

Cron is running inside the container. If I bash into the container as `www-data` and run: `/usr/local/bin/php app/console my:command -e=stage` it also works correctly so I'm at a loss as to why it's not playing ball as a crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are not available to cron. So the command and parameters were using a `BASE_DOMAIN` environment variable which was `null` when being run by a scheduled cron task.

To get around the issue, the base domain was passed as an argument to the command and the host was set on the request context as follows:

```
$context = $this->router->getContext();
$context->setHost($input->getArgument('host'));
```

And then updating the cron to include the host.

Comment: An incomplete answer in terms of code and the command. How to pass the base domain via command ?

Comment: `--host=example.com` (https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html)

Comment: Incidentally, I seem to have had this exact problem twice and come up with two solutions! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970558/symfony-command-not-reaching-execution-when-run-by-cron